# Azure Functions C# yellow circle exclamation and no log

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-functions

On my monitor for my functions, I see a yellow circle exclamation and no log.  I have about 5 functions, and I see this happen from time to time.  What's causing this?

[image]

Comment: What's function doing ? Btw Pls raise a ticket with MS..

Comment: It's running every 3 minutes, checking 2 databases and updating a row if something has changed.

Comment: Wow why the -1 rating for this?

Comment: @DanParker this usually indicates the function did not finish or there was a failure to write a monitoring event. If you can share an invocation id and the function app region, we can take a look to see if we can identify the cause.

Comment: @FabioCavalcante It's East Asia region.  The context ID is b8d6c1d4-4315-4f39-9a78-24525937b4e7 at 2017-07-19T01:42:10.0502775+00:00

It seems to happen every once in a while and be at 0 MS
Had another strange thing happen one time here as well:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4059fae0-6c1d-4cd0-aaaf-0fc4b4ba6de6/strange-behavior-wrote-to-wrong-log-file-and-caused-a-resend-from-azure-queue-storage?forum=AzureFunctions

Answer (score 1):

It means the function never finished executing. This could be because the process crashed before finishing. If the function is CPU or I/O intensive, a starvation issue may have caused the crash or inability to write the log.

Comment: Sounds like the consumption plan is no good for functions then.  I thought it's supposed to be free of CPU/memory issues (the functions I'm running shouldn't be using that much anyway)

Comment: Starvation may not be your issue. The consumption plan will scale out multiple function instances to load balance in the case of high overall CPU activity or invocation rates. That's generally extremely useful. But if a single function instance is too intensive, the consumption plan can't split it part, and hence it could lead to starvation issues.

Comment: Hmm, this is a very simple function though and it happened to a few of them yesterday, otherwise I haven't seen after that.  I haven't seen it since either.  MS is looking into it as well.  I'm wondering if I should switch off of consumption so I can see the CPU.